# trying to change the state of a submit button from disabled to enabled

Tags: javascript, java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Trying different ways to change the state of a button by removing the class "disabled". After having tried various suggestions that I found online I have still not been able to get it working as I would like it.
Below is the snippet of from the view

```
 <tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" onclick="enableSubmit()">I accept the 
    <a target="_blank" href="<c:url value='/TermsAndConditions' />" rel="nofollow" >terms and conditions
    </a> of this transaction
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="align: left;">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="<c:url value='/Cancel' />/${order.id}" role="button">
    <spring:message code="result.back" />
    </a>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
    <a id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary disabled" href="<c:url value='/Confirm' />/${order.id}" role="button" >
    <spring:message code="result.submit" />
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

below is lastest attempt I have tried

```
 <script>
        function enableSubmit(){
        $('#submitBtn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
 </script>
```

any guidance on what I am doing wrong will be greatly appretiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.submitBtn')
```

allows selecting the elements having the **CSS class** `submitBtn`. What you want is select the element which has the **id** `submitBtn`:

```
$('#submitBtn')
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, button still shows up as disabled  :(

Comment: Is this function actually called some time?

Comment: Fix your opening <script> tag (it's </script> in your question), and add console.log() calls or use the browser debugger to know if the function is called. Also, make sure you have included jquery.

Comment: console.log() added and I can confirm that 
<script src="resources/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> is there and the method is called
looks to be that the issue lies in the below:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedForm:130 enableSubmitForm:108 onclick

Comment: If $ is not defined, that means tha jQuery is not included. Check the path of the js file.

Comment: thank you the help with resolving this issue
have had to change it to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
</script>
        function enableSubmit(){
        $('#submitBtn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
 </script>
```

`.submitBtn` is for a class `#submitBtn` is for an id

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify a class not id of SubmitBtn.

Change `$('.submitBtn')` to `$('#submitBtn')`

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains a typo.

the . selects an element with a class, the # will select an ID.
since you used

```
function enableSubmit(){
        $('#submitBtn').removeClass('disabled');
}
```

this should fix it.